# Export Code Attribute

Tags: perl, attributes

I want to create a function which can be imported and used as a code attribute.
I am using `Sub::Attribute` to create the attributes.  The example given uses inheritance but I want to export and use it.  Hope my question is clear.

Code snippet to create an attribute:

```
package attpkg;

use strict;
use Sub::Attribute;
use Exporter 'import';

our @EXPORT_OK = ('Myattr');

sub Myattr : ATTR_SUB {
    my ($class, $sym_ref, $code_ref, $attr_name, $attr_data) = @_;
    print "@_";
    #$code_ref->();
    print "_____________\n";
}

1;
```

Code Snippet that tries to import the attribute but fails:

```
use strict;
use attpkg qw(Myattr);

sub pHelloWorld : Myattr {
    print "Hello World\n";
}

pHelloWorld();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub::Attribute secretly also creates a function called `MODIFY_CODE_ATTRIBUTES()` in the `attpkg` namespace. You'll need to export that too.